# Query to find the last 4 Tuesday from current date

Tags: sql, sql-date-functions

i'm working on bi report.
So i have a table with

```
occupancy ID | rent amount | Date of payment
```

and the rent is paid on every Tuesday of the week. i need a SQL query to find the last 4 Tuesday from the current date. it needs to be dynamic as the current date continues, it automatically needs to get the previous 4 tuesdays

Comment: I would suggest to point the exact RDBMS you use. Date-arithmetic is very vendor-specific

Comment: Don't tag spam. Your title said "SQL Server" yet you tagged [[tag:mysql]], [[tag:sql-server]] *and* [[tag:postgresql]]. *Only* tag the RDBMS you are really using, and **only** that RDBMS.

Comment: Though I will admit, a calendar table would be invaluable resource here.

Answer (score 0):

i am guessing, you are looking for right syntax for datetime functions.
here it is example of week number, month.. etc. and how to use it.
Hope, it will help you with query.

```
DECLARE @today         DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @todayDayName        VARCHAR(10) = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @today)
        , @todayShortDay       VARCHAR(10) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @today, 103)
        , @todayDATE           DATE        = CAST(@today AS DATE)
        , @todayDayNumber      INT         = DATEPART(DAY, @today)
        , @todayWeekNumberYear INT         = DATEPART(wk, @today)
        , @todayWeekNumber     INT         = DATEDIFF(WEEK, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @today), 0), @today) +1
        , @month               INT         = MONTH(@today)
select 
    @today as DayNow, 
    @todayDayName [TodayDayName], 
    @todayShortDay [TodayShortDay], 
    @todayDATE todayDATE, 
    @todayDayNumber [TodayDayNumber], 
    @todayWeekNumberYear TodayWeekNumberYear, 
    @todayWeekNumber TodayWeekNumber, 
    @month [month]


select top 100 
    UpdateDate, 
    [date] = CAST(UpdateDate AS DATE), 
    [DateName] = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, UpdateDate), 
    WeekNumber = DATEDIFF(WEEK, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, UpdateDate), 0), UpdateDate) +1,
    monthnumber = MONTH(UpdateDate)
from [dbo].TABLE 
where DATENAME(WEEKDAY, UpdateDate) = 'Tuesday'
```

[image]